# Find probability of number of first element $X_1$ in the bootstrapped sample from $X_{[n]}$

Tags: probability-theory, statistics

Let $K_n$ -- random variable, equal to number of elements of $X_1$ in the bootstrapped sample from $X_{[n]}$.

I need to find
$\lim \mathbb{P}_{n\to \infty}(K_n = k).$

Well, I've started from $\mathbb{P}_{n\to \infty}(K_n = k) = (1/n)^k(1 - 1/n)^{n-k} = \frac{1}{(n-1)^k}(1 - 1/n)^n = \frac{1}{(n-1)^k}(1 - 1/n)^n$, where second mult is $1/\exp$ in limit. But what can I do with the first one?

Comment: Is this the situation? You have an original sample of size $n$ and $X_1$ is one of the values appearing once.  You resample $n$ times with replacement from the original sample and you want to know the distribution of the number of times $X_1$ appears in the resample.  You also want to know what is the limiting distribution as $n \to \infty$.

Comment: $\mathbb P(K_n=k)= (1/n)^k(1 - 1/n)^{n-k}$ looks as if it is missing a ${n \choose k}$ term

Comment: I would have thought $\mathbb E[K_n]=1$ for all $n$ and you wanted the limiting distribution of a binomial distribution $Bin(n, \frac1n)$ as $n$ increases - this is well known

Comment: @Henry how can I show that $\mathbb{E}K_n$ is 1?

Comment: The expected number of resampled copies of $X_1$ plus the expected number of $X_2$ plus ... $X_n$ is $n$ and they are all equally likely, so the expected number of one of then such as $X_1$ is $\frac{n}{n}=1$.  (You can also use the corrected binomial  distribution of $K_n$ to get the same answer)